# How to prevent background scroll when multiple poppup opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have popup called `Products` and when a user clicks on any product a new popup is opened which contains `product information`. I prevent the background from scrolling when the popup is open using this CSS:

```
body.modal-open {
  position: fixed;
}
```

I remove this `position` property when the user closes the popup so that the background can start scrolling again.

The problem is that when I opened the `products` popup the background stops scrolling (which is fine) and after that when I opened the `product information` popup the background still stops (which is also fine) but when user closes `product information` the scrolling starts again.

I want to have it so that the window should only start scrolling when both popups have been closed. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please try to provide us a working code or snippet

Comment: what do you do on `body.modal-close` ?

Comment: @Shahroozevsky nothing

Comment: @Ced you can check it here www.deliveryswift.co

Answer (score 0):

CSS style attribute overflow-y: hidden; prevents background scroll if applied on the HTML element from where you want to remove scroll.
Try below on browser:
a) Open you page with popup on it.
b) Apply style overflow-y: hidden; on element from where you want to remove scroll. Scroll should disappear.
c) To achieve this dynamically you have write js code to append above style on desired element on click of popup trigger element. Only CSS wont be able to achieve your requirement as you need to do it dynamically.